# How to make Kendo Grid data culture specific?

Tags: kendo-ui, culture, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using kendo for displaying data to the different chart like Area or Bar Chart. . 
I want that column name to be culture specific that column name coming from the database

Is this possible ??

Give me solution

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are asking, but you can annotate the data field with an attribute `[Display(ResourceType = "MyApp.Resources.NameOfField")]`. Then create resource file for each language and the ASP.NET MVC will decide which resource file to load (depending on users language) and KendoUI will use this display name in the grid column header.

Comment: That I am knowing this but I want data that is coming dynamically from the database to be culture specific. .